# Gnome (gdm) logs in and immediately locks the console. The logs indiciate "WARNING: Could not get session id for session."

Tags: gnome, gnome3, d-bus, gdm, screen-lock

Immediately after login to gdm the screen locks and we get this error in the logs:

`gnome-session-binary[25582]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.`

Doing `rm -rf ~/.cache` prevents the screen lock and logs in successfully, but when we lock the screen (timeout or ctrl-alt-L) it spams this to the logs:

`journal: JS ERROR: Failed to open reauthentication channel: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: No session available#012_reauthenticationChannelOpened@resource:///org/gnome/shell/gdm/util.js:363:34#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22`

The system is CentOS 7.8.

Answer (score 0):

The first error actually provides the solution, but it is perhaps not obvious where to fix the problem.

Make sure you have this (<<<<<) in your /etc/pam.d/password-auth file and possibly the system-auth file as well:

```
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so  # <<<<<
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Note that the leading dash (-) is optional for log suppression if the file is missing.

**Also**: Make sure your /etc/pam.d/* symlinks point where you think they should.  In our case `authconfig` was updating the -ac files but we had our password-auth and system-auth symlinked elsewhere for "reasons".  A `diff` of the -ac and -custom versions was helpful in pinning this down.